# Content from a string into a array

Tags: objective-c

I have a string that needs to be put sorted(not in the high to low way), the string is set to separate each number with a comma and after every third number a space:

> 26,2496,1492252306 1049,99,68353132 860,99,59587920 4717,99,43863427 807,99,67243688 1382,99,37865117 1088,99,14810482 95,99,67711274 5,99,200000000 3310,99,25639438 75,99,157217334 1923,99,29678736 48,99,118806349 133,99,35055345 563,99,21098356 3410,99,17805574 47,99,62821143 2504,99,14821240 5,99,200000000 3076,99,19425499 474,99,31321799 3983,99,16825678 17826,99,13768252 1129,99,17249030 5393,99,14082021 338,120,137201472 2850,1944 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 4509,3988 3863,3987 2632,4148 5790,4105 -1,-1 -1,-1

i need to create some sort of association for each of the 3 numbers. kinda like a something along the lines of 2d array and a dictionary. any suggestion?

Comment: I don't really understand what is the question, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your string is saved in a variable named "myNumbers", do this:

```
NSString *myNumbers = @"26,2496,1492252306 1049,99,68353132 860,99,59587920 4717,99,43863427 807,99,67243688 1382,99,37865117 1088,99,14810482 95,99,67711274 5,99,200000000 3310,99,25639438 75,99,157217334 1923,99,29678736 48,99,118806349 133,99,35055345 563,99,21098356 3410,99,17805574 47,99,62821143 2504,99,14821240 5,99,200000000 3076,99,19425499 474,99,31321799 3983,99,16825678 17826,99,13768252 1129,99,17249030 5393,99,14082021 338,120,137201472 2850,1944 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 4509,3988 3863,3987 2632,4148 5790,4105 -1,-1 -1,-1";

NSArray *triples = [myNumbers componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

NSMutableArray *matrix = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSString *triple in triples) {
    [matrix addObject:[triple componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
}

NSLog(@"matrix: %@", matrix);
[matrix release];
```

Answer (score 0):

How about split the string with white space first, then split each of the splited items with comma like following algorithm?

```
threeItems = split main string with white space
for each itemString in threeItems
  threeItem = split itemString with comma
  do something with threeItem
end for
```

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you are trying to achieve but you can index items at the "do something part" into 2D array then sort them in the way you want. Depending on how you want to sort them, there might be better way to index them.